# Attributed string font formatting changes when dequeuing reusable UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsattributedstring

I have a `UITableView` that contains cells where I'm setting an `NSAttributedString` on a `UILabel`. The `NSAttributedString` has sections that are HTML bolded using `<b>%@</b> by <b>%@</b>`, and they render correctly on the first pass however when the cell is called again the entire string is in bold, rather than the individual sections.

I prepare the `NSAttributedString` with this function.

```
- (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForString:(NSString *)string forFont:(UIFont *)font {
    NSLog(@"Get attributed string");
    string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<style>body{font-family: '%@'; font-size:%fpx; color:#000000;}</style>",
                                              font.fontName,
                                              font.pointSize]];

    NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
    NSAttributedString *labelString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];

    return labelString;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple ways to solve this:

1)

In your custom UITableViewCell, you should implement `prepareForReuse`:

```
-(void)prepareForReuse{
    [super prepareForReuse];

    // Then Reset here back to default values that you want.
    self.label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12.0f];
}
```

2)

After you dequeue your table view cell in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you can do something like:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if(cell)
{
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 12.0f];
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, for some reason it would auto default back to a system font of size 17 but that's easy to work around.